# why does only READ me pop up on published github page

Tags: github

Whenever I publish my website on github, only the README thing pops up, not the actual HTML file that I had uploaded

Here take a look at my repo: https://github.com/arib0903/aditto.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured the [GitHub page publishing source](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).
If it is still set to None, you won't see anything:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/none-source-setting.png]